# How to Select distinct values in FOR XML PATH?

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xpath

Given the following tables where `T_DATA.ID = PARENT_ID` or `CHILD.ID`

**Name: `T_DATA`**

```
+----+------+--------+
| ID | CODE | VALUE  |
+----+------+--------+
|  1 | 3186 | value1 |
|  2 | 3186 | value2 |
|  3 | 3189 | value3 |
|  4 | 3189 | value4 |
|  5 | 3190 | value5 |
+----+------+--------+
```

**Name: `T_DATA_LINK`**

```
+-----------+----------+
| PARENT_ID | CHILD_ID |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |        3 |
|         1 |        4 |
+-----------+----------+
```

I want to return an xml structure like this:

```
<ITEM_LIST>
    <ITEM>
        <CODE>3186</CODE>
        <ROWS>
            <ROW>
                <ID>1</ID>
                <ROW_INDEX>0</ROW_INDEX>
                <VALUE>value1</VALUE>
            </ROW>
            <ROW>
                <ID>2</ID>
                <ROW_INDEX>1</ROW_INDEX>
                <VALUE>value2</VALUE>
            </ROW>
        </ROWS>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <CODE>3189</CODE>
        <ROWS>
            <ROW>
                <ID>3</ID>
                <ROW_INDEX>0</ROW_INDEX>
                <VALUE>value3</VALUE>
            </ROW>
            <ROW>
                <ID>4</ID>
                <ROW_INDEX>1</ROW_INDEX>
                <VALUE>value4</VALUE>
            </ROW>
        </ROWS>
    </ITEM>
    <ITEM>
        <CODE>3190</CODE>
        <VALUE>value5</VALUE>
    </ITEM>
</ITEM_LIST>
```

The `ROW_INDEX` is incremented by 1 for every `ROW`.

I need the `T_DATA_LINK` table to know whether an `ITEM` has a parent or not.

If it has a parent it means that there is more than one record with that `CODE` value and they need to be displayed as `ROWS`, otherwise it has to be displayed as a single `ITEM`.

**UPDATE**

I actually need to check the T_DATA_LINK table since there may be cases where an ITEM has a parent and only one record, but it still need to be displayed as a ROW.

@Shnugo I tried your solution, but even if now I get the correct values inside the ROWS, I get duplicates for each ITEM that has more than one record.

This is probably because I had to add to the GROUP BY the other fields I need to return with the SELECT which I didn't add to the example in order to keep it simpler.

For example, the ID need to be displayed at the ITEM level for the items which don't have any ROWS.

**UPDATE 2**

@Shnugo you are correct. Items 3 and 4 are the children of Item 1, but you don't see the relationship in the xml.

All the items are unique, always.

The items that are referenced in T_DATA_LINK are still unique, but are linked to each other in my application where they are displayed inside a table.
Basically the PARENT is the first column of the table and the children are the others columns.

This is the updated output I want to get.

ID should be always -1 for the items that have rows.

PARENT_CODE should be the CODE of the parent (if the item is a parent then it is equal to the CODE)

```
<ITEM_LIST>
  <ITEM>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <CODE>3186</CODE>
    <PARENT_CODE>3186</PARENT_CODE>
    <ROWS>
        <ROW>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <ROW_INDEX>0</ROW_INDEX>
            <VALUE>value1</VALUE>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <ROW_INDEX>1</ROW_INDEX>
            <VALUE>value2</VALUE>
        </ROW>
    </ROWS>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <CODE>3189</CODE>
    <PARENT_CODE>3186</PARENT_CODE>
    <ROWS>
        <ROW>
            <ID>3</ID>
            <ROW_INDEX>0</ROW_INDEX>
            <VALUE>value3</VALUE>
        </ROW>
        <ROW>
            <ID>4</ID>
            <ROW_INDEX>1</ROW_INDEX>
            <VALUE>value4</VALUE>
        </ROW>
    </ROWS>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <CODE>3190</CODE>
    <VALUE>value5</VALUE>
  </ITEM>
</ITEM_LIST>
```

Comment: I don't think sql server will save it the way you want.  You can use a programming lanugage like c# to easily read and save the xml.

Comment: @jdweng Why do you think SQL-Server cannot solve this?

Comment: This is a very good question! stand-alone example, clear question, expected output... +1 form my side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new answer... Please try to put all needed information into the initial question...

```
DECLARE @t_data TABLE(ID INT,CODE INT,VALUE VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @t_data VALUES
 (1,3186,'value1')
,(2,3186,'value2')
,(3,3189,'value3')
,(4,3189,'value4')
,(5,3190,'value5');

DECLARE @t_data_link TABLE(PARENT_ID INT, CHILD_ID INT)
INSERT INTO @t_data_link VALUES
 (1,3)
,(1,4);
```

--The CTE links the two tables and allows to handle them as one *derived* table

```
WITH Combined AS
(
    SELECT d.*
          ,d2.CODE AS PARENT_CODE
          ,COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY d.CODE) AS CountRows 
    FROM @t_data AS d
    LEFT JOIN @t_data_link AS dl ON d.ID=dl.CHILD_ID
    LEFT JOIN @t_data AS d2 ON dl.PARENT_ID=d2.ID
)
SELECT CASE WHEN c.CountRows>1 THEN -1 END AS ID 
      ,CASE WHEN c.CountRows>1 THEN c.CODE END AS CODE
      ,CASE WHEN c.CountRows>1 THEN ISNULL(c.PARENT_CODE,c.CODE) END AS PARENT_CODE
       --This part for elements with just one row per code
      ,(
        SELECT d2.ID
              ,d2.CODE
              ,d2.VALUE
        FROM @t_data AS d2
        WHERE c.CODE=d2.CODE 
          AND c.CountRows=1
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       )
       --This part for elements with more rows per code
       ,(
        SELECT d2.ID
              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))-1 AS ROW_INDEX
              ,d2.VALUE
        FROM @t_data AS d2
        WHERE c.CODE=d2.CODE 
          AND c.CountRows>1
        FOR XML PATH('ROW'),ROOT('ROWS'),TYPE
       )
FROM Combined AS c
GROUP BY c.CODE,c.CountRows,c.PARENT_CODE
FOR XML PATH('ITEM'),ROOT('ITEM_LIST');
```

The result

```
<ITEM_LIST>
  <ITEM>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <CODE>3186</CODE>
    <PARENT_CODE>3186</PARENT_CODE>
    <ROWS>
      <ROW>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <ROW_INDEX>0</ROW_INDEX>
        <VALUE>value1</VALUE>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <ROW_INDEX>1</ROW_INDEX>
        <VALUE>value2</VALUE>
      </ROW>
    </ROWS>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <ID>-1</ID>
    <CODE>3189</CODE>
    <PARENT_CODE>3186</PARENT_CODE>
    <ROWS>
      <ROW>
        <ID>3</ID>
        <ROW_INDEX>0</ROW_INDEX>
        <VALUE>value3</VALUE>
      </ROW>
      <ROW>
        <ID>4</ID>
        <ROW_INDEX>1</ROW_INDEX>
        <VALUE>value4</VALUE>
      </ROW>
    </ROWS>
  </ITEM>
  <ITEM>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <CODE>3190</CODE>
    <VALUE>value5</VALUE>
  </ITEM>
</ITEM_LIST>
```

XML will omit any NULL value. The `WHERE` clause in the subselects will return with `NULL` if there's nothing found...

Comment: @FabioL. I do not really understand the data within `data_link`-table, 3 and 4 are children of 1? Your data does not reflect this - or I do not understand it... Please check your question, add data for your corner cases and adapt the expected output. This might be clear for you, but it isn't for me...

Comment: I adapted your answer to my actual tables structure and it works beautifully. Thank you very much!